# GCM push notification message

Tags: android

I implemented Android app, I used notification payload to send notification message from the server. But the problem is, when I receive multiple notification, on clicking one of those notification, the desired activity is opened but the others not, I emphasize that i used notification payload and system creates the notification, so I cannot set flags.

this is in my server side :

```
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => getAllUsers(),
    'data' => $message,
    "notification" => array(
    "body" => "Hello !!!",
    "title" => "Hello from Server!",
    "icon" => "@drawable/ic_launcher",
    "color"=> "#03A9F4",
    "click_action"=>  "OPEN_MAIN_ACTIVITY"
    ),
);
```

this is the code in my Manifest file to handle clicking on that notication:

```
<activity android:name=".News" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="OPEN_MAIN_ACTIVITY" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Please post some code for better understanding!

Comment: If you can send the data from a server and then serialze this into a notification, then you can SURELY set flags on that Intent that is packed into the PendingIntent.

Comment: yes, I can manage it when I create the notification myself but I wanted to use notification payload